# Windows vps performance

Tags: windows, performance, centos7, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

Windows vps performance is not as expected while I see this message in /var/log/messages.

> [ 7283.526915] kvm [34279]: vcpu0 disabled perfctr wrmsr: 0xc2 data 0xffff

Its a KVM vps on 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 kernel and Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.12.0
Is this related ?

Comment: What performance did you expect? What are the numbers that you consider slow? What are the resources assigned to the guest? What workload is it running?

Comment: it takes around 5-10 seconds just to load explorer, cpu and ram usage is low in vps.
Vps is assigned 2Gb ram and 4 cores .
Server is not under load while server is having 48 cores

Answer (score 0):

No, this message is not related.

This warning message is reporting that the gust OS cannot access the PMU counters and should not be of any concern. The messages do not affect the functionality or performance of the operating system or the server and can be safely ignored.